# startService(sendIntent) firing more than once

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm doing an app for a bluetooth thermal printer. I've done the printing part already.

This is the code:

```
public void printText(View view)    
    {
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        if (b.getText().toString().equals("Choose Printer"))
            errorAlert("No Printer Selected");
        else
        {
            EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.printerText);
            errorAlert("Printing...");      
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            stopService(sendIntent);
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra("MAC", mac);
            sendIntent.putExtra("DATA", e.getText().toString()+"\n\n");
            sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.bluetoothtest",""com.example.bluetoothtest.MainActivity""));
            startService(sendIntent);
        }
    }
```

When I invoke printText the printer prints twice or thrice. It seems that startService(sendIntent) fires more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start a service twice or thrice. Read about the `startService` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29).

> Returns
>
> If the service is being started or is already running, the
> ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else
> if the service does not exist null is returned.

Try to debug your code, add 'Log' lines to fix the issue.